# aws load balancer http to https redirect not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BhOo.png)

https://boardarc.com -> working

http://boardarc.com -> now working, do not redirect to https

Sorry. Use Google Translator.

https connection is possible.
However, I cannot connect to http.

I looked up a lot of information but couldn't fix it.
What is the problem?

Comment: Can you also add a screen shot of `View/edit rules` ? Just want to make sure you are returning `HTTP_301 permenantly moved`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection is working, but you are using **wrong port**. HTTPS is **443**, not 433.

Please change your port in ALB to 443.

Comment: you have sharp eyes @Marcin

Comment: @BaluVyamajala This is one of these mistakes you could spend hours debugging. I was just lucky to notice it.